# Why does my HV monitor circuit (sometimes) fry components?

Tags: high-voltage, comparator, zener

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv60XR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a high-voltage monitor circuit that illuminates an LED when HV is present, shown above.  A couple of these boards have worked fine for months, while others exhaust a burning silicon smell and draw 500+mA before constant-current mode kicks in on my power supply.  All of the boards of a previous revision worked fine with an LM1717 op-amp instead of the LM339, but I moved to a comparator for rail-to-rail operation.

Probing this board is pretty tough, and due to safety restrictions I cannot use the finger test to determine which component gets warm, but I know the Zener regulates 10V fine at steady-state.

My thoughts are:

1. Do Zener diodes, in general, have a slow turn-on time?  I cannot find any literature on this, in datasheets or otherwise.  If so, I could see a high enough voltage develop on the input pin of the comparator to fry it (~50V).
2. If so, a small capacitor on the input pin to the comparator could limit the voltage rise until the Zener can start regulating.  Is this valid?  Since this is only for a human's eye, a few milliseconds of delay on the turn-on/-off won't matter too much.
3. Would a resistor in-line with the input pin help, too?  Say 1k?
4. Is there some other phenomenon I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Layout is obviously going to be critical here - can you post pictures of the layout or the PCB? It could simply be arcing or creepage.

Comment: Are you physically using a single 10M Ohm resistor?

Comment: What exact resistor are you using as R5? What voltage is it rated for? 5kV @ 10MΩ = 2.5W, so what power is it rated for? If that resistor breaks down or arcs over or anything, it'll expose the rest of your circuit to 5kV, which is unlikely to end well. Also, what voltages is the zener rated for?

Comment: @pjc50 I'll see what I can post, but it may be unallowable or much delayed.  I have been keeping the arcing in mind, though.

Comment: @Joren Vaes and marcelm, I'm using a SLIM-MOX104RD voltage divider rated for 10kV (http://www.ohmite.com/cat/res_slimmox.pdf)

Comment: Why are you feeding 50V into a circuit and expecting a 10V zener to simply dispose of the excess? Is there a design consideration you haven't told us that requires such a high input voltage into the 12V circuit, or could you use a 5Mohm resistance at position R5 to lower the anticipated input voltage to something within tolerances for the LM339?

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB it's a mix of limited part stock and legacy inheritance.  Kludging a small cap across the Zener would be much more practical than trying to kludge a HV resistor in parallel with R6, for instance, and such a resistor is probably not feasible to acquire.  But I'll look into it.  I would have certainly made some changes had I been put in charge of designing it, but assembled PCBs are here so I have to make the most of it.

Comment: Hmm...seems to me it *shouldn't* be too difficult to add a 2-4Mohm HV resistor in series with the input though? it seems that a chassis-mount resistor could be attached "in-line" on the HV line before it even reached the input on the board, thus making 0 PCB modifications necessary. -- I'm thinking that the 50V available voltage to the 10V zener is simply *asking* for a problem; any zener problems & POP goes the comparator; but if the voltage divider was only sending 10-15V for the zener to regulate...might be a different story (and lower the voltage-divider power dissipation too).

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB true, and what I forgot is that since the 'output' of the divider will only be ~25V I could use a regular old resistor (100k in parallel with R6) there.  And I hear ya about the Zener, too -- made me wince when I first saw the schematic.

Comment: [Here's one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-dale/ROX0752M00FKEL/ROX075-2.00MF-ND/2713096) I just found that might work for you, but I'm wondering why you need to add a resistor in parallel to R6...series resistor before R5 can do "the whole job," and doesn't require modifying your core circuit at all.

Comment: Issues with wiring to the PCB in question are why it'd be preferable to just tack in a resistor in parallel with R6.  Under other circumstances I'd put the resistor inline with R5, for I agree that that would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the issue wasn't related to the circuit, but cabling.  A pulsed high-voltage, high-current line was routed right underneath the PCB on some units, exposing the poor LM339 to extremely high E and B fields.  The units where proper cabling was employed did not have such problems, therefore I'm convinced therein lies the issue.

Future units, however, will employ a lower-ratio voltage divider on the comparator pins to prevent high voltages (>36V, which the pins are rated) appearing there.